# Is there a way to set my Facebook "Friends" list to always "Show All"?

Tags: facebook, friends, list

Is there a way to set my Facebook "Home> Friends> Edit Friends" list to always "Show All"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of April 2011, I don't think this is possible to do.  You could always [submit a feature request](http://www.facebook.com/help/?topic=suggestions) to allow for the customization of this setting.